# Use table from existing external database in my project

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database created out of my android  project.
There are some static informations as for example contact informations.

Instead of creating a new table and inserting those informations in my local project database, I would like to use the existing table and add it to my project.

Is this possible and if possible, how can i do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you may copy your already created database file in **Assets** or **Raw** folder and load it by copying it in a cache directory. Doing so will actually include your database file in your .apk file and you may access it when ever you want without any fear of loosing records in case if user clears the cache

Comment: Thank you Waqas, I will try this, but how to load this database from Assets folder?

Comment: this will help you to deal with your own databases: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/